# Google OCSP name resolution failure with Stubby

Tags: dns, ocsp

So, I recently started having problems with security.OCSP.require pref set to true in Firefox. I'm using Stubby (and dnsmasq as a cache).

dig ocsp.pki.goog reports "status: SERVFAIL", but dig +cd ocsp.pki.goog gives correct entries.

My stubby.yml config is as follows: https://0x0.st/oeTP.txt My resolv.conf has nameserver 127.0.0.1 and options edns0 trust-ad.

I don't know why this is. If I add GETDNS_TRANSPORT_{UDP,TCP} to Stubby's config, then it works, but as I'm using "Strict mode" I think I'm supposed to have only GETDNS_TRANSPORT_TLS.

What could be wrong with my setup?

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but normally at 99% level of confidence a given query resulting in SERVFAIL starting to work with `+cd` means a DNSSEC related problem. If you look at DNSViz output right now on the name, at https://dnsviz.net/d/ocsp.pki.goog/YugWug/dnssec/ it shows at least one fatal error, that only Google can fix. Hence the problem is most probably not on your side and what you observe is the correct output, even if it gives you a name resolution failure.

Comment: Need to focus and narrow doen the problem and what was tried.